# Stop Devices Deleting Songs On iCloud; iTunes Match

Tags: iphone, itunes

I want to delete songs from my devices, not from iCloud.

Can I change settings to prevent devices deleting songs from iCloud, i.e. delete from local device but not iCloud.

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a song from an iDevice connected to iTunes Match, only the local copy gets deleted. The song remains in the index and gets displayed with the iCloud icon.

The option to delete the cloud version as well is only given when deleting a song in iTunes on Mac or PC.

Answer (score 0):

I took my Mac offline and opened the music location in finder, closed iTunes and deleted the songs while iTunes was closed. ***Make sure you have a backup!***

I later discovered that one of the songs it matched from in the cloud was defective (had a glitch). Luckily I have a backup.

Haven't looked into how to deal with a full iOS device. I guess I thought that was all managed by *magic* like everything else in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your when your iPhone is connected to the computer it's set to manually managed instead of auto.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about how this solves the problem stated in the question?